# cordova builds giving EACCES error after upgrade

Tags: android, cordova

I have upgraded cordova via npm AND I had to run the command as root via sudo on OS X

Now, when I run "cordova build android -verbose", I get:

```
Error: spawn EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:302:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:380:9)
at exports.spawn (/Users/someuser/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
at GradleBuilder.build (/Users/someuser/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:213:12)
at /Users/someuser/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js:158:24
at _fulfilled (/Users/someuser/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/someuser/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/someuser/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
at /Users/someuser/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
```

My cordova version is 6.5.0 (I don't remember the version I had before)

I have the following Android SDK Platforms:

Android 7.1.1
Android 7.0

I have the following Android SDK Build-Tools installed:

24.0.2
25.0.1
25.0.2

I have linked

/Users/someuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates

to

/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates

Finally, I've run chmod -R 777 * in my project directory

Has anyone run into this and solved it?

Comment: i had same issues, and i am lazy, it wanted to put something in ~/Android, i have Sdk and tools there, so i just `sudo chmod -R a+rwx ~/Android` and now it works

Comment: @GCoda This didn't work for me on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the following:

1. Android SDK
2. Android Studio

and upgrading to the latest versions.

Then I made sure I was running android 6.2.1 as my cordova android platform

Then I did

- cordova platform remove android
- cordova platform add android

and it all worked

Comment: Why delete Android SDK? We can upgrade it. Any difference?